# Change layout depending of values in store

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia, nuxt3

I'm playing with Nuxt3 and Pinia.

I'd like to have two layouts: one for guest users and another for authenticated users.

app.vue

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
</script>

<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

layout.global.ts

```
import {storeToRefs} from "pinia";
import {useAuthStore} from "~/store/auth";

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to) => {
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    const {authenticated} = storeToRefs(authStore);

    const layout = computed(() => {
        return authenticated.value ? "authenticated-layout" : "default-layout";
    });

    setPageLayout(layout)
})
```

Every test I made result with the same error:

```
chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1449 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/core 
  at <NuxtLayoutProvider layoutProps= {ref: RefImpl} key="authenticated-layout" name="authenticated-layout"  ... > 
  at <NuxtLayout> 
  at <App key=3 > 
  at <NuxtRoot>
warn2 @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1449
logError @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1623
handleError @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1615
callWithErrorHandling @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1567
flushJobs @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1763
Promise.then (async)
queueFlush @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1676
queueJob @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1670
(anonymous) @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:7208
triggerEffect @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:614
triggerEffects @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:604
triggerRefValue @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1211
(anonymous) @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1371
triggerEffect @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:614
triggerEffects @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:599
triggerRefValue @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1211
set value @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1255
finalizeNavigation @ vue-router.js:2409
(anonymous) @ vue-router.js:2319
Promise.then (async)
pushWithRedirect @ vue-router.js:2287
push @ vue-router.js:2213
login @ login.vue:19
await in login (async)
(anonymous) @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:10436
callWithErrorHandling @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1565
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1573
invoker @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:9397
chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:9157 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')
    at parentNode (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:9157:30)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:7175:11)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:423:19)
    at instance.update (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:7212:52)
    at updateComponent (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:7039:18)
    at processComponent (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:6974:7)
    at patch (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:6436:11)
    at patchSuspense (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:2562:7)
    at Object.process (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:2481:7)
    at patch (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:6461:16)
parentNode @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:9157
componentUpdateFn @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:7175
run @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:423
instance.update @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:7212
updateComponent @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:7039
processComponent @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:6974
patch @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:6436
patchSuspense @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:2562
process @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:2481
patch @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:6461
componentUpdateFn @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:7171
run @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:423
instance.update @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:7212
callWithErrorHandling @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1565
flushJobs @ chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:1763
chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:7520 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'subTree')
    at move (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:7520:28)
    at move (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:7520:7)
    at Object.resolve (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:2789:11)
    at chunk-RAKT47ZN.js:2912:20
```

I'm quite new to Vue (I mostly use React).

Did I miss something? (SSR?). Is there another way in Vue.js to do that?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. The stack is too obscure and doesn't contain the explicit cause. The error means that something went wrong during the navigation. You may want to debug what happens in your own modules, i.e. login.vue here. Otherwise than the answer suggests, there's nothing to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use computed on your case. A simple validation like this would work.

Here is an example of how you can use dynamic layout content.

`~/middleware/layout.global.ts`

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(() => {
  const authenticated = false
  if (authenticated) {
    return setPageLayout('authenticated')
  } else {
    return setPageLayout('default')
  }
})
```

If you set the `authenticated` to `true` it will change the layout to `authenticated`.

Create the layouts

`~/layouts/authenticated.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Authenticated</h1>
    <div>
      <slot />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

`~/middleware/default.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Default Layout</h1>
    <div>
      <slot />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Set the layout in the page

`app.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLayout>
      <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>
```

`~/pages/index.vue`

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: 'authenticated'
})
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Home page</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Tested and it works.

Comment: I change const authenticated = false with const {authenticated} = storeToRefs(authStore); and the condition by  if (authenticated.value). It doesn't detect the change when I set authenticated = false|true in the store. I need to reload the page.

Comment: @Sancho, you don't need `storeToRefs`. You can remove that. See working example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-pfxwrj?file=stores%2FuseAuthStore.ts